# if (isset($_GET['editpersonnel'])) not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP/MySQL project with a modest CMS.

I am working on a page called - `index.php?page=personnel` - where I am trying to update a personnel in the database.

On that page I have an included form with - action="?editpersonnel" method="post"

Meanwhile, in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['editpersonnel'])) {

... // update personell ...

header('Location: .');

exit();
```

... idea being that when the form is submitted the script updates the personnel and then redirects back to itself.

Unfortunately, when I submit the form, instead of reloading the desired 'index.php?page=personnel'  the script simply ads 'editpersonnel' to index.php so I end up with

```
index.php?editpersonnel
```

And by the way, none of the updates happen either...

Actually, it completely disregards everything after  - `if (isset($_GET['editpersonnel']))` - so I guess that's were the problem is...

Any ideas what might be causing such a behavior?

p.s.

Form is dynamically populated, so this is its page source:

Name:

            

        

        

            

        

    

    

        

            

                Email:

            

        

        

            

        

    

    

        

            

                Set password:

Comment: provide assigning a value to `editpersonnel` like `index.php?editpersonnel=foo`

Comment: just figured out `method="post"` in your code... you have to set the `method` to `GET` if then in you PHP you want to access the variable throught `$_GET`

Comment: Use as form action: action="?editpersonnel=xxx"
xxx can be anything, but "editpersonnel" needs to have a value,
otherwise the value for $_GET['editpersonnel'] is nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_GET` to be able to use something like that. Change your form's method to GET.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="editpersonnel" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the form data by `POST` method and then trying to access them via `GET`

You have two possible solutions, see which one is more suitable for your case.

*Change form method to `GET`*

```
<form action="?editpersonnel" method="GET">
```

**OR**

*Change access method in PHP to `POST`*

```
if (isset($_POST['editpersonnel'])) {

   ... // update personell ...

   header('Location: .');

   exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ponciste, I tried the both of them and although they make perfect sense, they are not working for me, i.e. I am still being redirected to index.php?editpersonnel. BTW, I copy/pasted that method="POST" in combination with if (isset($_GET - from a Learnable course and it works in their example??? I left the question on their forum as well.

Comment: i don't think it can work in their example as well. Btw can you explain me better what do you want to achive? Also, can you post more code? (esp. the form)

Comment: I am trying to post the form for the last 20 minutes, but it won't let me post anything within <>

Comment: well, `<form action="index.php?page=personnel" method="GET">` and then  in `index.php` if you access `page` this way `if(isset($_GET['page'])) echo $_GET['page'];` it should work..

Comment: Thanks @ponciste, but the action cannot be static - in this instance it is 'page=personnel' but it can be 'page=list' (that's what I meant when I said in the question that it is dynamically populated.

Comment: The action cannot be static - in this instance it is 'page=personnel' but it can be 'page=list' (that's what I meant when I said in the question that it is dynamically populated. It all boils down to using the a single form and a single php file for different situations (editing, adding, deliting personnel etc)

Comment: what about building a url like `?page=personnel&action=edit`?